# Can I use templates with this syntax?

Tags: c++, templates

I found this StackOverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749990/c-function-dynamic-data-type-definition) while looking for some sort of way to abstract data types.

I wanted to create an IO helper function that takes as parameters a class(more often than not a string) and a data type.

I'm also doubting the `variable y` part. I don't know if the syntax is correct if I wanted y's value to change.

```
template <class message>
template <typename variable>
void inputCheck(message x, variable y)
{
    cout << x;
    cin >> y;
    // if input y is invalid, call inputCheck again
    // else, keep the input and assign it to y located outside this function
}
```

Comment: Are you asking whether it's possible to deduce the type of `y` at runtime based on what is available in cin? If so, it's not possible. The type must be known at compile-time. You can template the type however, in which case you must select what type you wish to look at compile-time when call it. I also don't know why you chose to have `y` as an argument given that you overwrite it immediately and it's not passed by reference. Remove the argument and simply let the user specify the expected type at the call site: `inputCheck<int>("Enter an integer");`

Comment: I just want the function to be flexible so as not to create more functions with exactly the same definitions and with only different parameter data types like `void f1(int x)` and `void f2(char x)` with exactly the same definitions, only differing in variable type to be used for cin.

Comment: I think you need to put both template declarations into one line (`template <class message, class variable>`) but it should work otherwise. Did @Mark not answer your question already?

Comment: Then I suggest letting the compiler automatically deduce the message type and manually specifying y's type. For what it's worth, you can do: `template<typename Msg, typename Input>`, all on one line. I also recommend passing `x` by const reference, and not passing `y`, but rather, constructing it yourself inside the function. Also note that `typename` is more appropriate even for Msg, as a string literal ("Hello") is a `const char*` (even though class and typename are functionally equivalent when used this way).

Answer (score 1):

```
template <class OutputType, class InputType>
void InputCheck(const OutputType &x, InputType &y) {
  cout << x;
  cin >> y;
}
```

Also pay attention at `InputType &y`: `y` needs to be passed as a referenced so that its modification can be seen outside the function.

`x` is passed as `const &` because if `OutputType` is large (a struct, a string or a vector etc.) passing by reference is way faster. The `const` assures that it won't be modified.